# Trying to parse JSON data from webhook but returns error

Tags: python, json

I am able to receive the webhooks just fine but when I try to add code to read the data it returns an error. Am I parsing it incorrectly?

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    print("webhook kaldt")
    event_json = json.loads(request.body)
    status = event_json['status']
    print(status)
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

If i remove the `status`variable and the print line, then everything works out. It's just as soon as I try to parse the data.

The data from event_json looks like this

> {"created": 1326853478, "livemode": false, "id":
>   "charge.succeeded_00000000000000", "type": "charge.succeeded",
>   "object": "event", "request": null, "pending_webhooks": 1,
>   "api_version": "2019-03-14", "data": {"object": {"id":
>   "ch_00000000000000", "object": "charge", "amount": 100,
>   "amount_refunded": 0, "application": null, "application_fee": null,
>   "application_fee_amount": null, "balance_transaction":
>   "txn_00000000000000", "billing_details": {"address": {"city": null,
>   "country": "DK", "line1": null, "line2": null, "postal_code": null,
>   "state": null}, "email": null, "name": "qwewqwq", "phone": null},
>   "captured": false, "created": 1553170537, "currency": "dkk",
>   "customer": null, "description": "My First Test Charge (created for
>   API docs)", "destination": null, "dispute": null, "failure_code":
>   null, "failure_message": null, "fraud_details": {}, "invoice": null,
>   "livemode": false, "metadata": {}, "on_behalf_of": null, "order":
>   null, "outcome": null, "paid": true, "payment_intent": null,
>   "payment_method_details": {"card": {"brand": "visa", "checks":
>   {"address_line1_check": null, "address_postal_code_check": null,
>   "cvc_check": "pass"}, "country": "US", "exp_month": 1, "exp_year":
>   2022, "fingerprint": "JKbTj7sZqbPMQJ9p", "funding": "credit", "last4":
>   "4242", "three_d_secure": null, "wallet": null}, "type": "card"},
>   "receipt_email": null, "receipt_number": null, "receipt_url":
>   "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1E4YZiB2MQ8LEk6k/ch_1EGPo5B2MQ8LEk6k47xo3CcZ/rcpt_EjtbkjCrHE8bfSS0Xxa5iW3UBNjqK7C",
>   "refunded": false, "refunds": {"object": "list", "data": [],
>   "has_more": false, "total_count": 0, "url":
>   "/v1/charges/ch_1EGPo5B2MQ8LEk6k47xo3CcZ/refunds"}, "review": null,
>   "shipping": null, "source": {"id": "card_00000000000000", "object":
>   "card", "address_city": null, "address_country": "DK",
>   "address_line1": null, "address_line1_check": null, "address_line2":
>   null, "address_state": null, "address_zip": null, "address_zip_check":
>   null, "brand": "Visa", "country": "US", "customer":
>   "cus_00000000000000", "cvc_check": "pass", "dynamic_last4": null,
>   "exp_month": 1, "exp_year": 2022, "fingerprint": "JKbTj7sZqbPMQJ9p",
>   "funding": "credit", "last4": "4242", "metadata": {}, "name":
>   "qwewqwq", "tokenization_method": null}, "source_transfer": null,
>   "statement_descriptor": null, "status": "succeeded", "transfer_data":
>   null, "transfer_group": null}}}

Comment: "when I try to add code to read the data it returns an error" => are we supposed to guess which error ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prettify your json, you'll see that there is not a 'status' property in the root object

You could try

```
event_json['data']['object']['status']
```

**Formatted json**

````
{
    "created": 1326853478,
    "livemode": false,
    "id": "charge.succeeded_00000000000000",
    "type": "charge.succeeded",
    "object": "event",
    "request": null,
    "pending_webhooks": 1,
    "api_version": "2019-03-14",
    "data": {
        "object": {
            "id": "ch_00000000000000",
            "object": "charge",
            "amount": 100,
            "amount_refunded": 0,
            "application": null,
            "application_fee": null,
            "application_fee_amount": null,
            "balance_transaction": "txn_00000000000000",
            "billing_details": {
                "address": {
                    "city": null,
                    "country": "DK",
                    "line1": null,
                    "line2": null,
                    "postal_code": null,
                    "state": null
                },
                "email": null,
                "name": "qwewqwq",
                "phone": null
            },
            "captured": false,
            "created": 1553170537,
            "currency": "dkk",
            "customer": null,
            "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
            "destination": null,
            "dispute": null,
            "failure_code": null,
            "failure_message": null,
            "fraud_details": {},
            "invoice": null,
            "livemode": false,
            "metadata": {},
            "on_behalf_of": null,
            "order": null,
            "outcome": null,
            "paid": true,
            "payment_intent": null,
            "payment_method_details": {
                "card": {
                    "brand": "visa",
                    "checks": {
                        "address_line1_check": null,
                        "address_postal_code_check": null,
                        "cvc_check": "pass"
                    },
                    "country": "US",
                    "exp_month": 1,
                    "exp_year": 2022,
                    "fingerprint": "JKbTj7sZqbPMQJ9p",
                    "funding": "credit",
                    "last4": "4242",
                    "three_d_secure": null,
                    "wallet": null
                },
                "type": "card"
            },
            "receipt_email": null,
            "receipt_number": null,
            "receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1E4YZiB2MQ8LEk6k/ch_1EGPo5B2MQ8LEk6k47xo3CcZ/rcpt_EjtbkjCrHE8bfSS0Xxa5iW3UBNjqK7C",
            "refunded": false,
            "refunds": {
                "object": "list",
                "data": [],
                "has_more": false,
                "total_count": 0,
                "url": "/v1/charges/ch_1EGPo5B2MQ8LEk6k47xo3CcZ/refunds"
            },
            "review": null,
            "shipping": null,
            "source": {
                "id": "card_00000000000000",
                "object": "card",
                "address_city": null,
                "address_country": "DK",
                "address_line1": null,
                "address_line1_check": null,
                "address_line2": null,
                "address_state": null,
                "address_zip": null,
                "address_zip_check": null,
                "brand": "Visa",
                "country": "US",
                "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
                "cvc_check": "pass",
                "dynamic_last4": null,
                "exp_month": 1,
                "exp_year": 2022,
                "fingerprint": "JKbTj7sZqbPMQJ9p",
                "funding": "credit",
                "last4": "4242",
                "metadata": {},
                "name": "qwewqwq",
                "tokenization_method": null
            },
            "source_transfer": null,
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "status": "succeeded",
            "transfer_data": null,
            "transfer_group": null
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Sorry, I ain't that familiar with JSON yet. I've only used it in a very few instances where I had to. But your answer is totally correct and it fixes my problem. So thank you for that and sorry about the not formatted JSON data.